# Effect of a metal(rod or plate) placed between two current carrying wires

Tags: electromagnetism

What happens to the force between two current carrying wires (in same or opposite direction) when a metal rod or plate(without current) is placed between them?

Comment: By placing a metal rod between the wires you've essentially created a short-circuit between both systems, so the current between both wires would be the same. What do you think will happen?

Comment: You misunderstood my question.The metal rod is simply placed between them.It is not touching the two wires . It is placed like this     |  |  |

Comment: I see, sorry I thought you were talking about a case like this |-|. In that case, I would expect that the magnetic field induces some variation on the distribution of superficial charges in the metal rod/plate placed between both wires. This could potentially change slightly the magnetic field and thus the force between both wires (I'm not sure now if we could have an analytical expression), but it shouldn't be too much unless you're dealing with very high currents.

Comment: Force will decrease or increase?

Comment: @SachinBhattarai It will increase a little bit in practically all realistic practical configurations. If the plate inside is ferromagnetic (i.e. steel plate), it might increase significantly. If the plate is superconducting, it will hugely decrease (superconducting materials expel magnetic field lines from them, only the field lines capable to avoid the plate will affect the wires).

Answer (score 1):

If the currents (presumably DC) flow in two independent circuits, connecting them with a metal rod won't produce any additional current and, therefore, any additional magnetic field.

If the rod is made of a ferromagnetic material, the distribution of the existing magnetic field near the rod will change a bit and, to that extent, the force between the wires could slightly change as well.

If the rod is made of a non-ferromagnetic material, the changes of the magnetic field should be negligible, so the force between the wires should not change.

Comment: You misunderstood my question.The metal rod is simply placed between them.It is not touching the two wires . It is placed like this | | |

Comment: @SachinBhattarai The answer would be the same and for the same reason.